# curl facebook authorize

Tags: php, facebook, curl

Facebook has updated their authorize method, now use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
client_id="APPID"
&redirect_uri="CALLBACK_URL
&response_type=token
&response_type=code%20token
```

can get the token more easier than before. I tried into the browser, the url address could return:

```
http://localhost/facebook/#access_token=140***&expires_in=5381&code=AQDx8SXR***
```

So I tired use curl, but result is `1`, so how to do correctly? Thanks.

```
<?php header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<?php
$appid= "**MY APP ID**";
$callback_url= "** CALLBACK URL **";
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=".$appid."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($callback_url)."&response_type=token&response_type=code%20token";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$token_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt');
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

between other OPTS

Comment: I think you can remove that  _CAINFO and try it